# Photoshop batch image action: how to change background to white

Tags: background, automation, batch-processing, actions

I am trying to create an action in Photoshop cs6 to Batch Change image background to white.

I’ve attached a few samples of the JPEGs to change.

If you can show the techniques for this,it would be much appreciated

Thanks for your time.

John

[Horsehide jacket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Hdw.jpg)

[image: 50s Dress]!

[Chinese dress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ii58.jpg)

Comment: Any batch command is going to be difficult because the backgrounds are so inconsistent. Every image you posted is going to require some manual labor to extract well. "Batching" would only work well if you have consistent backgrounds such as green screens or other uniform backgrounds.

Comment: it could be posible if you shot with a tripod and shot one empty one without the object to cut out.

Comment: as Scott said, you can try shooting on a blue or green screen, then have you Action adjust the screen color to white. You still have to watch out for color casting (reflected light) showing up on the clothing, and any clothes with colors too close to the screen would still need manual adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

A batch command for your images is **not possible**. The backgrounds vary far too much for any extraction to be automated. Each of your posted image would require *manual* alteration of a mask/extraction to maintain quality.

If you **reshoot the photos on a greens screen** then you may be able to achieve some automation in removal of a single solid color (green screen) across images.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently with photos of rings. If you want a really nice clean edit then, say for product images, then manual editing is probably the route you'll have to take.

If you want to batch them, reshoot everything on a green screen and make sure you have a stable light source. Although results may still not be perfect.

Alternately give the background removal tool a whirl in Photoshop, scaling the image down after may reduce visible imperfections.

[image: background tool]

Some people find this method very therapeutic...

Answer (score 0):

try using Batch Image Background Remover and Changer on Android. This app perfectly suits your needs as it is best for working on multiple images at once and allows adding new backgrounds to multiple images and saving them all at the same time
You can download it from here > https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enscyd.batchbackgroundremover